# Adding Array like data in Zend Framework 2 Sessions

Tags: zend-framework2

Im wondering how to achieve the following:

I have this Session Container created by a factory:

```
        $container = new Container('Fans');
        $container->setExpirationSeconds('219867583');
        return $container;
```

then i'm creating an instance in my controller like this:

```
$this->sessionService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SessionService');
```

Now i want to add something to the Session:

This one works fine:

```
$this->sessionService->team = 'TEST';
```

But what i want to achieve is the following

```
$this->sessionService->team[0] = 'Team Name 0' // This doesn't work;
$this->sessionService->team[1] = 'Team Name 1' // This doesn't work;
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($this->sessionService->team);
```

The Output looks like this:

```
<pre>string(9) "TEST" </pre>
```

I don't know if i misunderstood something or do something wrong.

Does anybody know how to do it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the magic `__get()` functionality in PHP. Because `Zend\Session` uses `__get()` to supply access to session variables, you cannot access them like arrays. What does work, is the following:

```
$team = array();
$team[0] = 'Team Name 0';
$team[1] = 'Team Name 1';
$this->sessionService->team = $team;
```

Comment: This works. Because i had to reuse it i wrap this functionality in a Service. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an array?

```
$teams = array();
$session->teams = $teams;
$session->teams[0] = 'blubb';
```

If you first assign it to be a string, it will remain a string. Make it an array and use it as an array, too ;)

Comment: This didn't work in context of the Zend\Session or did i miss something ?

Comment: @Sam I struck with  handling multidimensional array in session container. Could you pls explain how we can handle it ? Every time the session array gets changed but not updated in an array.

Comment: @Sam Pls find the thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713047/multidimensional-array-session-container-in-zend-framework-2)