# Zend Framework 2 - Sessions containing multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, session, zend-framework, shopping-cart

Suppose i have the following set of data:

```
$foobar = array(
    "foo" => array (
       "foo1" => 1,
       "foo2" => 2,
       "foo3" => 3
    ),
    "bar" => array (
        "bar1" => 1,
        "bar2" => 2,
        "bar3" => 3,
    ),
);
```

In standard PHP, i could do the following:

```
$_SESSION['foobar'] = $foobar;
```

Then, to call values, by example bar2:

```
$_SESSION['foobar']['bar']['bar2'];
```

But what about doing this in Zend Framework 2?

I have already set bootstrap with all parameters for session manager, and container has been set with it. Sessions get created. So, if i do, by example:

```
$session = new Container('foobar');
```

and put a value in there:

```
$session->foo1 = 1;
```

this works. Same if i decide to put an array as session variable:

```
//placing the $foobar array defined before
$session->foobar = $foobar;
```

But i don't know how can i call values. Supposing i want foo2, i'd do

```
echo $session->foobar->foo->foo2;
```

expecting it would output '2', but i get an error instead:

So i tried doing

```
echo $session->foobar['foo']['foo2'];
```

but this returns another error.

So now i don't know what should i do to gather those data, or how could i store session variables differently. I need this to make a shopping cart, so foo and bar are different products. How could i do this?

Comment: What error did you get from `$session->foobar['foo']['foo2']`? I would have expected that to work.

Comment: @Tim Fountain Extremely strange: i get no error now...i was getting Illegal offset yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. First of all i created the parent offset this way:

```
$session->offsetSet("foobar", new ArrayObject());
```

(you need `use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject;` on top of your script).

Now i can create anything from there:

```
$session->foobar->foo = "foo1";
$session->foobar->bar = "bar1";
```

and so going on.
To get them, it's as easy as it should:

```
echo $session->foobar->foo; //returns foo1
```

I hope this will help someone.